# Error in mouse move after double click in datepicker of a C1FlexGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker, c1flexgrid

**Build :** C1Flexgrid v.2.5.20053.230
.Net 4.0 using C# WinForms

I have a C1Flexgrid on my form with multiple data populated as

```
//cfg is C1FlexGrid, pDataTable is DataTable

cfg.Clear(ClearFlags.UserData);

foreach (DataColumn dCol in pDataTable.Columns)
{
    cfg.Cols.Count += 1;
    iCol = cfg.Cols.Count - cfg.Cols.Fixed;
    cfg.Cols[iCol].Name = dCol.ColumnName;
    cfg.Cols[iCol].Caption = dCol.ColumnName;
    cfg.Cols[iCol].DataType = dCol.DataType;

    switch (dCol.DataType.ToString())
    {
        case "System.DateTime":
        {
            cfg.Cols[iCol].Format = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
            break;
        }
        case "System.Decimal":
        {
            cfg.Cols[iCol].Format = "N3";
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
cfg.DataSource = pDataTable.Copy();
```

When I double click on the datepicker pop-up to select a date and then move the mouse, the app crashes.

`edit`
To add to the concern, no errors if I use enter and arrow keys to shift focus from datepicker pop-up to next cell.

Any ideas as to if the cause is "my creation" or a bug on C1Flexgrid??

Comment: please explain pDataTable's structure. I think it has something to do with it. Also, how are you adding a Framework 2 specific build in your .Net 4.0 project?

Comment: @nilay: The pDataTable is my query result, generally, an ID (numeric), with text, date, decimals, Lookup text and id's. All are native.

As for framework specific builds, i'm not aware. I have the dll added as reference and license in the `licx`.

Comment: the block you see is a generic function to load procedure results to C1grid on the UI

Answer (score 0):

There are two confusing things in your problem description. First is the initialization of DataTable : **pDataTable** and second is your **environment information**. It is unknown how you've added a Framework 2 specific build in your .NET 4.0 project. Please go to [C1Pre-Release](http://prerelease.componentone.com) to find the most current flexgrid build or update your project with [this build](http://prerelease.componentone.com/dotnet40/c1flexgrid/2014-t2/C1FlexGrid.4_4.6.20142.835.zip).

*Follow these steps to troubleshoot your problem:*

1. **Change the project framework to .NET 4 complete profile**. You can do this by right clicking your project in Solution Explorer. Select Application Tab. Change your target framework to '.NET Framework 4'
2. **Update your C1FlexGrid reference**. You can do this by clicking references node of your solution in solution explorer. Remove the C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.2 from it by deleting it. Add a new reference by updating with [this build](http://prerelease.componentone.com/dotnet40/c1flexgrid/2014-t2/C1FlexGrid.4_4.6.20142.835.zip).
3. **Run your application**.

If this doesn't solve your issue, the root problem would be your pDataTable initialization.

See the following snippet:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int iCol;

        pDataTable.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        pDataTable.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        pDataTable.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        pDataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        pDataTable.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        pDataTable.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        pDataTable.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        pDataTable.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        pDataTable.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

        this.cfg.Clear(C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.ClearFlags.UserData);

        foreach (DataColumn dCol in pDataTable.Columns)
        {
            cfg.Cols.Count += 1;
            iCol = cfg.Cols.Count - cfg.Cols.Fixed;
            cfg.Cols[iCol].Name = dCol.ColumnName;
            cfg.Cols[iCol].Caption = dCol.ColumnName;
            cfg.Cols[iCol].DataType = dCol.DataType;

            switch (dCol.DataType.ToString())
            {
                case "System.DateTime":
                    {
                        cfg.Cols[iCol].Format = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
                        break;
                    }
                case "System.Decimal":
                    {
                        cfg.Cols[iCol].Format = "N3";
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        cfg.DataSource = pDataTable.Copy();
    }
```

The **only difference** in this snippet apart from environment is the **structure of DataTable**. When I compiled , there was no crash observed when I double click on the datepicker pop-up to select a date and then move the mouse.

You can download the working project from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9JoECGThrxwMEJpQ01rX1V6QTA/edit?usp=sharing)